# restTemplate string to LIST Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Hi I have searched a few topics here, but I couldnt find an answer. I need to convert a JSON string from a Spring Rest call to a List. I want to pass those to my JSP so I can display in a table with JSTL or anything else. This is what I have that works.

--Service Class--

```
public String callGetService(Operations operations) { 
          String URL = Operations.getServerSelected(); 
          String URI = URL + "?" + "Name="+ operations.getName() + "&" 
          + "RID=" + operations.getrID() + "&" + "Account=" + 
          operations.getAccount() + " "; 

         ResponseEntity < String > rs = restTemplate.exchange(URI, 
        HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity < String > 
           (createHeaders("app", "pass")), String.class);

           String result = rs.getBody(); 

                                             `
           return result;

          }
```

---Controller----

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView callsGetService(Operations operations) {

    String WS = webService.callGetService(operations);

    return new ModelAndView("gerResults","keyJstl",WS);

  }
```

----JSP----- I need to return a JSON LIST so I can put it into a table..

keyJSTL prints below

```
      {"Name":"JACK" , "rID": 2, "Account": 23421, "ResponseCode":"GET" }
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? if so, please fill in the details

Comment: You're using `RestTemplate` at the lowest level possible. Did you read the reference documentation? Additionally, have you considered using Feign?

Comment: I just need the JSON thats printed on my JSP Currently to be put in a list so I can use it for a table using JSTL. When I tried using JSON PArser it give me an error saying your format is not JSON. Also I tried 'ParameterizedTypeReferece<list<Operations>>()' and got a 400 Error.

Comment: @chrylis im not sure what that is.

Comment: You can write "Holder.class" instead of "String.class" . The "Holder.class" is an object you have to create and in this object you can define Entities or DTOs as list, spring will map them for you...

Comment: Markus G, can you give me an example?

Comment: You need to first create a class with list which you are visualizing, once it is created then you need to map the json to that object. So first create a sample picture of output as JSON which you are expecting then you can use site like jsonschema2pojo.org to create java class out of that response